# how show the distinct value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a contact and language table,`contact` table with column like below also

```
   id   Contact group   Media   E-mail                  Nationality        Country                      City      Area  Gender  Married Children    Drivers license

   107     Contactgroup1    SMS     nasir.kv01@gmail.com       India           United Arab Emirates         Dubai             Male     No       
   108     Contactgroup1    SMS     abdulrahim922@gmail.com    Pakistan        United Arab Emirates         Dubai             Male     Yes
```

for `language` table like below

```
id  language
1   English
2   Hindi
```

also i am using helper table name `contactlanguage` that matching the contact id with the language id its like this

```
contactid   languageid
   107         1
   108         1
   107         2
```

I am running this query in search function,

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM contact
INNER JOIN contactlanguage ON contact.id = contactlanguage.contactid
INNER JOIN language ON contactlanguage.languageid = language.id
WHERE isdeleted = 0 AND language.language in ('English', 'Hindi', '')
```

the same data was repeating like this

```
id   Contact group     Media    E-mail                  Nationality        Country                      City      Area  Gender  Married Children    Drivers license

107     Contactgroup1   SMS     nasir.kv01@gmail.com       India           United Arab Emirates         Dubai             Male     No   

107     Contactgroup1   SMS     nasir.kv01@gmail.com       India           United Arab Emirates         Dubai             Male     No
```

i want to show only one data can any one tell me how to do that,thanks

Comment: Well, you are requesting both languages `language.language in ('English', 'Hindi', '')`. Choose the one you want. Or, in this case, replace `*` with the data you actually need.

Comment: You are explicitely asking for all contact-language combinations (by joining them). What *do* you want to see? All contacts for which one or both languages apply? All contacts with a string listing the languages ('English,Hindi' in your case)? What else?

Comment: On a properly normalized database "DISTINCT *" is a rather nonsensical idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you explicitly list only columns from the contact table instead of using `SELECT *` you will avoid duplicates caused by a contact having more than one language.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        contact.id,
        contact.`Contact group`,
        contact.Media,
        contact.E-mail,
        contact.Nationality,
        contact.Country,
        contact.City,
        contact.Area,
        contact.Gender,
        contact.Married,
        contact.Children,
        contact.`Drivers license`
FROM contact
INNER JOIN contactlanguage ON contact.id = contactlanguage.contactid
INNER JOIN language ON contactlanguage.languageid = language.id
WHERE isdeleted = 0 AND language.language in ('English', 'Hindi', '');
```

For what it's worth you should be explicitly listing the columns you want anyway. [It is not good practice to use `SELECT *`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) in production code.